# MongoDB Aggregate - How to use values of previous stage as a field name in next stage?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have an aggregation query like this:

```
...
{
    '$unwind': {
      path: '$modifier'
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
        'date': {
          '$dateToString': {
            'format': '%d/%m/%Y', 
            'date': '$updatedTime'
          }
        }
      }, 
      '$$modifier': { '$sum': 1 }
    }
  },
...
```

and I would like to use `modifier` values, a result of the previous stage (`$unwind`), as a field in the next stage (`$group`). The detail is in the picture below. How should I accomplish it?

[MongoDB aggregation question detailed picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mnPN.png)

Current:

This is the output of `$unwind` stage:

```
updatedTime:2020-03-27T11:02:43.608+00:00
modifier:"james@email.com"
```

```
updatedTime:2020-03-27T11:02:43.608+00:00
modifier:"eric@email.com"
```

This is the output of `$group` stage :

```
_id: { date:"27/03/2020" }
modifier:1
```

Expected:

the output of `$unwind` stage:

```
updatedTime:2020-03-27T11:02:43.608+00:00
modifier:"james@email.com"
```

```
updatedTime:2020-03-27T11:02:43.608+00:00
modifier:"eric@email.com"
```

This is the output of `$group` stage:

```
_id: { date:"27/03/2022" }
james@email.com:1
eric@email.com:1
total:2
```

Notice that "james@email.com" and "eric@email.com" come from `$unwind` stage which is before `$group` stage. `total` is the total of `modifier` (examples: 'james@email.com' and 'eric@email.com') values.
Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not straight but You need to group by both the properties `date`, `email` and do another group by only date and construct the array of modifiers and do replace that in root,

- `$group` by `updatedTime` and `modifier` and get total count
- `$group` by only date property and construct the array of object of `modifier` and `count` in key-value pair
- `$arrayToObject` convert that key-value pair into object
- `$mergeObject` to merge required properties like we added `date` property and above array to object operation result
- `$replaceRoot` to replace above merged object in root of the document

```
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "date": {
          "$dateToString": {
            "format": "%d/%m/%Y",
            "date": "$updatedTime"
          }
        },
        "modifier": "$modifier"
      },
      "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id.date",
      "modifiers": {
        "$push": {
          "k": "$_id.modifier",
          "v": "$count"
        }
      },
      "total": { "$sum": "$count" }
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          { 
            "date": "$_id",
            "total": "$total"
          },
          { "$arrayToObject": "$modifiers" }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! But what if there is more than one email in the `$group` stage output and I would like to have the total number of each modifier?
The expected output is : 
`{ "date" : "27/03/2020", "james@email.com" : 5, "eric@email.com" : 3, "total" : 8 }` ?

Comment: this query will give your expected result. have you tried passing multiple modifiers?

Comment: Yes, it gave the the expected result like : 
`{ "date" : "27/03/2020", "james@email.com" : 5, "eric@email.com" : 3}`

However, what if I want to add a new field labelled `total` as the total values of all modifiers? Like :
`{ "date" : "27/03/2020", "james@email.com" : 5, "eric@email.com" : 3, "total" : 8 }`

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it! I have updated the question and requirements. Also, I am sorry that I did not include the `total` field as an expected output or a requirement in the question. I will be more careful and will upvote after getting 15 reputation (not able to upvote as currently I only have 13., sorry..)